# c# %userprofile% filepath, Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, path

I need to execute Chrome with certain arguments, on both 32 and 64 bit computers. Since there isn't an executeable for Chrome in the same location on 32/64 bit alike, I did a try/catch for both.

Problem is, the 32bit lies in `C:\Users\%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`
and no matter how I try `Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile` it refuses to execute.

```
  private void bypassbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       try
        {

            var info = new ProcessStartInfo
            {

                FileName = @"C:\Users\%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",
                Arguments = "--proxy-server=10.10.10.10:9999 " +
                            @"--user-data-dir=C:\filterbypass " +
                            "www.example.com"
            };
            MessageBox.Show("Use Wisely");
            var process = Process.Start(info);
          }

        catch  { }
```

I've tried

```
 private void bypassbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       try
        {
     var datapath   @"%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
 var filePath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(datapath);
            var info = new ProcessStartInfo
            {

                FileName = filePath,
                Arguments = "--proxy-server=10.10.10.10:9999 " +
                            @"--user-data-dir=C:\filterbypass " +
                            "www.example.com"
            };
            MessageBox.Show("Use Wisely");
            var process = Process.Start(info);
          }

        catch  { }
```

I'd appreciate if anyone could tell me where I'm going wrong, or if there's a better way to launch chrome on 32 & 64 bit. Thanks.

Comment: It may be better to ask your user to enter their chrome location.. they may install it into their own custom location also

Comment: @Sayse In our work environment users can only install to the default location. And, I don't think they know well enough to navigate to their install location themselves.

Comment: Have you tried using `Environment.UserName` instead of `%UserProfile%`? That will get you the username of the current signed in user.

Comment: Also is there a reason you make some of the strings verbatim and some not in your ProcessStartInfo Arguments? Mainly the first argument passed, the white space on the end, if needed, may not be passed as expected.

Comment: @CalebB It was the only way I could get it in. I know they are correct because when I launch on a 64bit computer with only the file path changed, it works correctly. Also, would you be able to show me an example of how I would  use  `Environment.Username`?

Comment: Okay I understand. You can create a new string such as: `string x = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System)).ToString() + @"Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";` The first line also get's the main drive then just pass this string into the argument or wherever you need.

Comment: I have the string, but I can't pass it to the FileName now. FileName = x;...it wants a path

Comment: What's the exception it's giving you? Can you update your code with the string you constructed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70601/discussion-between-eyeseesharp-and-calebb).